# Green light presentation for a project

Tags: product-management, product-owner

I'm working on a project to be pitched to a owner who needs to greenlight the production.

I'm wondering if there is any format to follow for the presentation.

Since, this is first time I'm making this, if some one can help me out with the process I should follow for my thinking, it'll help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an example of a situation where you need to propose something to someone and you need them to agree to your proposal.

You need to work out what is important to the audience, what information will be key for them in their decision making and what barriers might exist in their mind to agreeing your proposal(s). Then you need to tailor your pitch to address all these points and then ask for their agreement.

These things will differ from project to project, but obvious points to cover are:

- Scope - What are you proposing they get in return for approving your proposal. I assume they will get something out of the "production", a new building, a new software system, a new website, or whatever it is. They probably need to know in fairly fine detail what they get for their money and, just as important, what they *won't* get for their money
- Cost - What will your proposal cost them in hard cash
- How long will it take - Having approved your proposal, how long is it until they take delivery of whatever it is you are producing?
- How do you intend to do it? What assurances can you give them that they will get what they paid for on time, to cost and within agreed quality metrics? What controls and tests will you put around the production to ensure this happens?